# How to prevent user from inserting a Date that is in a range of dates?

Tags: database, couchdb

I'm using CouchDB for syncing offline and online data. The problem is that since couchDB hasn't a layer between client and server, validation is kinda poor. The only field that can be unique is the _id.
For example if you want to make a sure the field "phone" is unique, you need to make sure that the phone number is somewhere in the _id (555-666-777_username) and the field "phone" is 555-666-777.

My problem is: I have a calendar that makes events that cannot overlap each other. An event has a start time and an end time. How can I make sure that the user won't put a date between the start time and end time.

One idea is instead of making one document with a startTime and endTime. It's to make various documents that have dates within the user's desired range.

Example: User selects a range between 2018-09-02 and 2018-09-10, so I'll create 8 documents with a _id composed of {date}{username}.

If you think couchDB doesn't suit to this kind of stuff, I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: This sort of check is best done in your application logic, rather than the Database layer. Even if you find a way to enforce this in CouchDB, once you sync, you may find you have conflicts.

Comment: I know couchDB is different, but I was always told to validation on backend. Do mobile apps do such validations in frontend?

Comment: Who always told you to do validation on the backend? And why?

Comment: if the only validations are in frontend, the user can modify the source code right? Maybe in C or C++ that wouldn't be a problem but I'm using Electron. Correct me if I'm wrong, but in terms of source-code security, Electron only has ASAR, which can be easily converted to source code.

Comment: Data integrity should, indeed, be validated on the server.  But that's not enough in your situation, since you're not just talking about data validity, but about overlaps, which can only be handled manually.